# Como incluir um arquivo de configuração do vim em outro?

Tags: vim

Estou reorganizando/refazendo meus arquivos de configuração do vim e gostaria de deixar configurações de linguagens diferentes em arquivos separados.
Algo assim:

```
.vimrc
.vimrc.python
.vimrc.ruby
.vimrc.cpp
.vimrc.js
...
```

Não preciso que as configurações de uma linguagem sejam carregadas *somente* para aquele tipo de arquivo, todas podem ser carregadas ao mesmo tempo. Gostaria apenas de deixá-las em arquivos separados, mais fácil de organizar e tudo mais.

Como faria um "include" de um arquivo de configuração em outro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o comando `source` para chamar outros arquivos de configuração, para isso é só colocar no seu arquivo de configuração principal (.vimrc) o seguinte:

```
source ~/.vimrc.python
source ~/.vimrc.ruby
source ~/.vimrc.cpp
source ~/.vimrc.js
```

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava! Valeu!